# In Python, I can print HTML to the browser, how can I ensure that the CSS that relates to it also get "printed"

Tags: python, html, css, browser

// After the "Content-type..." declaration...

```
print """<html>\
<head>
<title>Create Survey</title>
<link href="styles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">   
</head>
<body>...."""
```

Comment: Print the CSS too? Your HTML is a giant hardcoded string, so you can just look at it, find the relevant CSS, and hardcode that too.

Comment: What exactly do you need from the output? Are you looking for something a web browser could understand and display? Are you trying to debug it? Are you trying to find the dependencies of an arbitrary web page so you can download everything necessary for offline use?

Comment: I am using CGI to get data from a form then I process the data and depending on which kind of data it is I modify an HTML page and I display it to the user... There is a styles.css file related to it, and I would it currently does not work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using something like CGI to "print" text based on a web request you should rely on your web server (Apache for example) to "print" the content back to the requesting client based on where your CSS file is located in the htdocs directory.

However if you are just wanting some output in a command line window you could do...

```
print file('/path/to/your/file/styles.css').read()
```